# MYSQL Insert Query not Executing

Tags: php, mysql, database, insert

I've been trying to execute a MySQL Query in a PHP script, but for some reason it isn't working. I've looked over it dozens of times, but can't seem to find what's making it invalid. All of the variables are correct, including all of the associated tables. Any thoughts?

```
 <?php 

        $db->query("INSERT INTO main (rodovia, km, estado, preco_eixo, preco_moto, autosum, preco_2ed, preco_3es, preco_3ed, preco_4es, preco_4ed,
                    preco_5ed, preco_6ed, preco_7ed, conc, updatedon) VALUES ( '$rodovia', '$km', '$estado', '$preco_eixo', '$preco_moto', '$autosum',
                    '$preco_2ed', '$preco_3es', '$preco_3ed', '$preco_4es', '$preco_4ed', '$preco_5ed', '$preco_6ed', '$preco_7ed',
                    '$conc', NOW() )");

    }

?>
```

Comment: first value in VALUES will be in single quotes and show the error you are getting

Comment: Syntax errors/typos are off-topic `( $rodovia'` - Having used http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.error.php  would have told you that. Edit: oh lovely edit.

Comment: An error should be generated - can you provide that

Comment: `they are ALL numbers`  I'm not sure how forgiving MySQL is but SQL Server would not accept numeric columns that are quoted as you are doing.

Comment: I added the single quote, it was just something I deleted by accident when pasting it to StackOverFlow, it still doesn't work.

Comment: `preco_4es, preco_4ed` <= missing comma. Tell us that isn't another typo.

Comment: Got it, it wasn't a typo, I actually tabbed in the middle of the query to organize it visually (as a noob I did not know it would make the whole thing fail). I got it fixed now . Thank you all for being so quick to reply.

Comment: You're welcome, but that doesn't tell us exactly what you did as far as details go. I don't think you should keep your question up. You can delete it, as it won't serve the community here, sorry.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error was actually something else entirely, I tabbed inside the query to keep it visually organized and that messed up the whole thing.

Forgive me for such a silly mistake and thank you guys for helping me learn how to debug these things on my own in the future.

Comment: You still will be passing numbers as strings, like '13', '32', etc.  This is syntactically incorrect.  You should remove the single quotes to pass numeric values.

Comment: @DNoe that shouldn't matter. MySQL will convert those.

Comment: Functionally, no but that's why I said syntactically incorrect.  It is poor practice and likely to confuse any other developers who might look at the code in the future.

Comment: Furthermore, If the database driver was ever switched to something more picky about data types than MySQL, it could cause the script to break.  Just because it doesn't matter at the moment doesn't mean it won't matter in the future.

Answer (score 1):

Remove the single quotes.  This is causing the inputs to be cast to strings.

```
 $db->query("INSERT INTO main (rodovia, km, estado, preco_eixo, preco_moto, autosum, preco_2ed, preco_3es, preco_3ed, preco_4es, preco_4ed
            preco_5ed, preco_6ed, preco_7ed, conc, updatedon) VALUES ( $rodovia, $km, $estado, $preco_eixo, $preco_moto, $autosum,
            $preco_2ed, $preco_3es, $preco_3ed, $preco_4es, $preco_4ed, $preco_5ed, $preco_6ed, $preco_7ed, $conc, NOW() )");
```